# How to call a Generic method with dynamic properties in C#

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, generic-list

I have the a few methods that have similar signature and was trying to convert them into one generic one without the use of interfaces.

```
 public List<MultiSelectDropdown> ConvertListOfJobStatusToDropdownListClickable(List<JobStatus> js) {
        var list = new List<MultiSelectDropdown>();
        if (js != null && js.Count >= 1) {
            list = js.Select(item => new MultiSelectDropdown { Name = item.StatusValue, Value = item.id.ToString() }).ToList();
        }
        return list;
    }


    public List<MultiSelectDropdown> ConvertListOfCUsersToDropdownListClickable(List<cUser> users) {
        var list = new List<MultiSelectDropdown>();
        if (users != null && users.Count >= 1) {
            list = users.Select(item => new MultiSelectDropdown { Name = item.User_Name, Value = item.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

This is what I would like to do; pass in a list with two properties.

```
List<MultiSelectDropdown> ddlForClientUsers = ConvertToMultiSelectDropdownList(listOfClientsForUser, n => n.Client_Id, v => v.Client);

List<MultiSelectDropdown> ddlForJobStatus = ConvertToMultiSelectDropdownList(listOfJobStatus, n => n.Id, v => v.JobName);
```

This is the method I have tried but not sure how to get item.propName  and item.propValue to work.

I get **"Cannot resolve" propName  and propValue** in the method below

Is this possible?

```
 public List<MultiSelectDropdown> ConvertToMultiSelectDropdownList<T, TPropertyName, TPropertyValue>(List<T> listOfT, Func<T, TPropertyName> propName, Func<T, TPropertyValue> propValue) {
var list = new List<MultiSelectDropdown>();
        if (listOfT != null && listOfT.Count >= 1) {
            list = listOfT.Select(item => new MultiSelectDropdown { Name = item.propName, Value = item.propValue }).ToList();
        }
        return list;
    }

public class MultiSelectDropdown {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the properties of your MultiSelectDropdown are strings, your functions should return those as well. And to invoke the functions, you have to write them like `propName(item)` instead of `item.propName` - that is the property syntax, and you indicated you didn't want to use interfaces.

```
public List<MultiSelectDropdown> ConvertToMultiSelectDropdownList<T>(List<T> listOfT, Func<T, string> propName, Func<T, string> propValue) {
    var list = new List<MultiSelectDropdown>();
    if (listOfT != null && listOfT.Count >= 1) {
        list = listOfT.Select(item => new MultiSelectDropdown { Name = propName(item), Value = propValue(item) }).ToList();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Or, to keep it nice and generic, call .ToString() on the result of the passed in func - could be fun getting dates to play nice though ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are really close, with just a slight mistake. The line (reformatted to prevent scrolling):

```
list = listOfT.Select(item => new MultiSelectDropdown 
                                  { 
                                      Name = item.propName, 
                                      Value = item.propValue 
                                  }).ToList();
```

needs to be:

```
list = listOfT.Select(item => new MultiSelectDropdown 
                                  { 
                                      Name = propName(item), 
                                      Value = propValue(item)
                                  }).ToList();
```